# How to disable listview row when click second time on it

Tags: android

I have a list view which sends data to server on click on its item. I want to disable the item (row) of listview which I have sent to the server so the user cannot send the data again to the server. Please help me.

here is my listview listner code in main activity :

```
    obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {




            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("Order_No", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderForm.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

when i clicked on listview item it took me to next activity which sends data to the server. What I want is, that when the data id send to the server so listview item become disable in main activity so user will not be able to send data again any idea?

Comment: on the onClickItem, check first if you have already sent the data for that item, if yes, don't do anything. The thing is *how* are you going to save the *status* of each item. It could be using the *tag*, or using a model option if your adapter is fetching the data acoriding to some java objects .... or or or ... (would be better to share some code)

Answer (score 1):

Set a tag for the view that you click on. Then when you click on it for the second time check if it has already been set

```
obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
       If(arg1.getTag().toString().equals("1")) return;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg1.setTag("1").;
        int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
        dataBundle.putInt("Order_No", id_To_Search);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderForm.class);

        intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
});
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                               at sales.com.salesproj.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:129)

Application crash when I click on listview item and it shows this error message on if condition..please help